# PL/SQL - need to do some conditioned calculations

Tags: plsql

I am a beginner in pl/sql so don't be too harsh.

I have a table with Column_A(Current month amount) and Column_B (previous month amount) as number. I need to write a condition for some calculations: "column_A - Column_b=result. **If result > 0** (meaning that there is an increase in current month compared to previous), **the result + column_A**.

I don't know how to write this one.

Comment: Please try to post some sample data and desired result to clarify your question (formatted text). Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, but i am doing it manually. I have 2 with clauses: one for calculations on current data and one for previous. Then i export them to excel, create new column to do A - B. The filter them by any result being greater than 0. Then the results from the filter, i add them to column D (in excel) and sum up with column A to calculate an absolute increase.
Problem is i have over 4000 results :(

Comment: Show us your stored procedure. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like below.

```
    UPDATE your_table SET column_A= 
         ( CASE  
         WHEN (column_A - Column_b)>0 THEN (column_A +(column_A - Column_b))              
         ELSE  (column_A)
         END )
```

This will check for all records that have a difference greater than zero and will update the column_A with the result which is a sum of Columns_A and the difference.

Hope this helps. Wish you a great learning!

Edited:
Well if you are just trying to manipulate data for display then you can simplify your query as below, which will do the same functionality.

```
    SELECT (CASE  
         WHEN (Current_month_amount - previous_month_amount)>0 THEN 
              (Current_month_amount +(Current_month_amount - 
               previous_month_amount))              
         ELSE  (Current_month_amount)
         END ) AS Current_month_amount, 
         previous_month_amount,
         (Current_month_amount - previous_month_amount) AS Amount_Difference
         from table_1
```